# MySQL: delete row if exist in other table with condition

Tags: mysql

I need to delete rows from 'old_battles' table, if it exists in 'battles' table with condition:

delete the row from 'old_battles' if it existed in 'battles' and 'old_battles.status = "finished"'

note: old_battles.id = battles.id

tables structure:
battles:

```
id     status
1     finished
2     cancelled
3     on progress
4     finished
5     finished
```

old_battles:

```
id     status
1     finished
2     cancelled
3     on progress
4     finished
5     finished
```

my query:

```
delete from old_battles 
where old_battles.id in

(
select ob2.id
from old_battles ob2,battles b
where ob2.id = b.id
and ob2.status = 'finished'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following

```
mysql> create table battles (id int, status varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into battles values 
    -> (1,'finished'),
    -> (2,'cancelled'),
    -> (3,'on progress'),
    -> (4,'finished'),
    -> (5,'finished');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table old_battles like battles;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into old_battles values
    -> (1,'finished'),
    -> (2,'cancelled'),
    -> (3,'on progress'),
    -> (4,'finished'),
    -> (5,'finished');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The following is the query to delete

```
delete ob from old_battles ob 
join battles b on b.id = ob.id where ob.status = 'finished';


mysql> select * from old_battles ;
+------+-------------+
| id   | status      |
+------+-------------+
|    2 | cancelled   |
|    3 | on progress |
+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```